# Bootstrap - Navbar not dropping down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was learning bootstrap, than, I'm not expert.
The code I write was following the video.

Everything works correctly, except one thing.
When my viewport collapse the navbar menu, and I click the button to expand, the menu expand between the navbar-brand and navbar-right.

In the examples I saw, the menu should expand below the navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a href="#">Projeto</a>
        </div>

        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Minha Conta</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quem Somos</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Redes Sociais
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Google+</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Fale Conosco</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C2kM4/

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: For me everything works fine (Google Chrome Version 35, Mac OS 10.10)

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. In Chrome everythink works correctly. I tested in Firefox 30.0 before.

Comment: Now tested on FireFox Version 30, Mac OS X 10.10 - I see what you are talking about. There seems to be a specific css default property in Firefox that causes the difference. You may consider asking the same question directly in the authors git repo so that they can fix it https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues ;)

Answer (score 0):

In jsfiddle you could be clicking on the spot that's covered by the "Result" span.  Everything is running fine for me (using Firefox 30.0).

Comment: It's "working" on both browsers but it looks different. Try it on both and you will see it.

Comment: Very interesting, I see what you guys are talking about now.  And thanks for the follow-up :)